# PSReadline history - delete one entry from history list

Tags: powershell, psreadline

While customizing my PS profile with the great PSReadline [sample example](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/blob/master/PSReadLine/SamplePSReadLineProfile.ps1), I had the idea to try to delete a specific history entry from the history `ListView` format.

For example I have the following
[image: Powershell Listview with history command to delete]

Ideally, I'd like to delete the highlighted entry from the history with the "`Del`" keystroke, but I don't know how to script that or get started by using the `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler` CmdLet

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The source is the file stored at path `(Get-PSReadLineOption).HistorySavePath` - so you simply need to remove the corresponding line(s) from that file to purge the command from the history

Comment: Thanks Mathias, I should have been more specific. I'm aware of the file location and I know I can manually remove the item but I wanted to have a convenient way to interact with the PSReadLine history to delete a specific part with some sort of shortcut instead of manually opening the file each time. Pretty sure it's possible to target this file and remove a specific match (in this case the buffered command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not ideal, it can be slow depending on the size of your history file, but this worked in my session. The caveat is that even if you remove a line from the `.HistorySavePath` file, the history item will still be visible as a completion item until you restart the session. Based on [PSReadLine Issue #494](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/494), the way you can *"refresh"* without restarting is to clear the history and re-add the content lines excluding the item to remove.

```bash
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+Shift+Delete -ScriptBlock {
    $in = ''
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::GetBufferState([ref] $in, [ref] $null)

    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($in)) {
        return
    }

    $historyPath = (Get-PSReadLineOption).HistorySavePath

    # only way to "refresh" the history in the current session is to clear it
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::ClearHistory()
    $content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($historyPath)
    Clear-Content $historyPath

    foreach ($line in $content) {
        if ($line.StartsWith($in, [System.StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
            continue
        }

        # and re-add it (excluding the line to remove)
        [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AddToHistory($line)
    }

    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::DeleteLine()
}
```

Comment: That's a clever way to do that. Thanks ! I've tried it on a 5k lines history file. Takes a couple of seconds (which I assume is linked to the history rebuild loop) but works as expected.

Comment: @Douda made a mistake in the code, please use this updated version instead. `[Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AddToHistory(...)` already appends to the history file, so the `StringBuilder` logic can be removed completely (I guess this also explains why it can be so slow)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I did compare both version and it's indeed much faster.